# From How far can the camera look an object in OpenGl in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to OpenGL android, but know some basic concepts like projection and camera views. 
we can change the position and orientation of camera. But,**when i move camera more away from an object the object disappears** .
For example: Below is my camera view and the co-ordinates of rectangle.

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -7, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

float rectCoords[] = {  
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
};
```

if I am correct the camera is 7 units away from the rectangle which is on XY plane and camera is 7 units away from rectangle on negative z axis looking towards the origin whose top is pointing towards positive y-axis.

When I change -7.0f i.e the z coordinate of the camera, to -7.1f(i.e i am moving the camera away from the rectangle) the rectangle disappears, **that means the maximum distance the camera can see is 7 units from it**. Correct me if i am wrong, if not then how can i make to see the object more than 7 units visible from camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vanishing point of objects based on camera distance in OpenGL (and 3D graphics in general), is the 'far plane distance'. It is part of the definition of the [view frustum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum), which is a general term in geometry, and is used to describe the 3D viewing volume. See this question ([Why does OpenGL have a far clipping plane, and what idioms are used to deal with this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949155/why-does-opengl-have-a-far-clipping-plane-and-what-idioms-are-used-to-deal-with)) for an explanation of why the far-plane exists. Most fixed function rendering pipelines also add the ability to add user-defined clip planes (including OpenGL's [glClipPlane](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClipPlane.xml)), so the far plane may not be the only explanation for objects vanishing based on distance. Programmable shader pipelines usually do not respect user-defined clip-planes, so their use is less popular recently.

The 'far plane distance' is part of the equation that forms the projection matrix. See [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) for a very detailed description for calculating the projection matrix, and its usage. You haven't shown your projection matrix, but presumably the far plane is either directly or indirectly defined as `7.0`.

Comment: yes you are correct, i haven't checked that ,indeed i don't know that plane exists. Thank you for correcting me,this is my frustum Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix1, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

Answer (score 0):

bro!if u hav a `myReshape` function in your code,,,just go to `gluperspective()` function,,in that increase the last value...ur issue will be solved.

ex: `gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.1, 500.0);`

increase 500.0 to 1000.0

Comment: Please, format your code [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)